# Managing web software versions by clients requests

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, iis-7, web

I need some consulting on a deployment issue on web applications . 
Let say I have many web apps installed on my web server (WCF service , ASP.NET site, Silverlight app , Static web app , and thing you can host on IIS).

My main problem , I need to manage these application version up to my clients. 
Example : Today I have Wcf service with version 1 , all the clients work with , after next month I release version 2 and I need to install it separatly on IIS and start move clients one by one to it . 
Same thing can happen to any application type I have .

Is there a modern way I can do that .

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Nuget and set up a feed your clients can use. Full versioning capabilities included:

http://nuget.codeplex.com/

http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2012/05/09/An-Introduction-to-Nuget.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy your WCF service version (such that 2 versions can co-exists), you can make use of application configuration files to manage what service each individual application points to. So after you deploy the new version of your service, you simply go through each applications web.config file and modify it to point to the new service when you desire.